# Grails run-command ask for application class argument

Tags: grails, command

I'm using grails 3.2.9 version. And trying to create custom command. I need a command because I need to have access to spring beans. So the code is simply like this:

```
class MyTestCommand implements GrailsApplicationCommand {

boolean handle() {
    def bean = applicationContext.getBean('myBean')
    bean.doSomething()
    return true
}
```

When I run it as

```
grails run-command my-test
```

I'm getting an error: "Missing application class name and script name arguments"
I'am able to add application class as last param and everything seems works, but the question is, why I should add it? Does grails doesn't know about its Main Application class? I did some research about and there is no answers, in each examples i se only command name without Application class. But as I understand from [this source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-console/src/main/groovy/grails/ui/command/GrailsApplicationContextCommandRunner.groovy) we should pass main class always. Am I missed something?

Comment: Your example works for me, in a simple standalone project.  Do you have something unusual in your build.gradle or elsewhere that would prevent grails from finding your main class?

Comment: I'm new in grails and trying to add this to existing project. If I create an empty one and add this command it also works without any additional parameters, so this is pretty strange for me. Projects starts as usual like grails run-app, maybe you can point me where can be problems with finding application class ?

Comment: Your Application.groovy (note the capital A, not "application.groovy" which is a different file.  Confusing, I know.) is where the main method runs.  That file us usually pretty short, like static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

Comment: This file is created as usual. Actually IntelliJ IDEA generate its, and there is no logic in it

Comment: I mean no logic except starting grails application : )

Comment: Did you find a solution @OldDed?

Comment: I have the same in Grails 4.0.11, did you find a solution?

Comment: For 4.0.11 this fix solved it for me :https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11588  by adding `runCommand {
  systemProperty "spring.devtools.restart.enabled", false
}` to `build.gradle`

Comment: Need to set `systemProperty "spring.devtools.restart.enabled", false` as well in `5.1.1`